# Teradata Compression Tools

Tags: compression, teradata, multivalue

Any recommend multi value compression tools for Teradata? (Except from Atana Suite and Prise Tools. Their trial versions do not show output or enough test to get convinced that I should aquire this)

Comment: With some creativity you can use the biased values in the statistics of a column to generate a list of values to compress. You can shred the XML output from SHOW STATISTICS at the column level and generate the DDL to run a script that applied the compression.

Answer (score 0):

MultiValueCompression (MVC) is placed in the DDL of the Table. So you can do it by your own.
We had a simple Python (can be Perl, Shell, whatever as well) that check for TOP X values of the column via SQL, then apply these to your DDL and then populate the DDL (CREATE new, INSERT Data from Old, Swap-Tables, Drop/archive old one).